# how to install genymotion?

Tags: software-installation

```
me@Yes-ME:~/Downloads$ bash genymotion-2.2.2_x86.bin

Installing to folder [/home/me/Downloads/genymotion]. Are you sure [y/n] ? y


[/home/me/Downloads/genymotion]: current user cannot write into this folder
You should install this package in your home folder or with admin rights, using sudo
Aborting
```

I am getting this error while installing genymotion

Comment: not duplicate , issue different.

Comment: what does `ls -l ~/Downloads/genymotion` say?

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod +x genymotion-2.2.2_x86.bin
sudo ./genymotion-2.2.2_x86.bin
```

execute them from terminal.

Comment: it is giving same error that current user cannot write in to this folder

Comment: you sure you doing with sudo ?

Comment: I am using sudo but it is giving me same problem. I am trying to install genymotion with virtual box.